# Splitting the elements of a list by some separator in the same list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
array([nan, 'Stressful day', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea', 'Drank tea',
       'Ate late:Drank coffee', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Worked out',
       'Drank tea:Worked out', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day',
       'Drank coffee', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day:Worked out',
       'Drank coffee:Worked out', 'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea',
       'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea:Worked out',
       'Drank tea:Stressful day', 'Drank tea:Stressful day:Worked out',
       'Drank coffee:Stressful day:Worked out',
       'Drank coffee:Stressful day',
       'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day', 'Worked out',
       'Ate late:Drank coffee:Worked out'], dtype=object)
```

these are unique values from the column of a dataframe,

as you can see they are combination of other values like 'Drank coffee:Drank tea' is a combination of 'Drank coffee' and 'Drank tea'. I want those unique elements for this list.

What's the quickest way to create that list? Is there any inbuilt function in python libraries for this sort of thing?

Expected output:

```
array([nan, 'Stressful day', 'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Ate late',
       'Worked out'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Maybe look at a combination of [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=split#pandas.Series.str.split) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.Series.explode)

Comment: do you want only those values where there is a colon in them right now? ie. can you show me what you want

Comment: Regarding your Java question that you deleted, you may want to read [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `a` the input array, you could use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
out = pd.Series(a).str.extractall('([^:]+)')[0].unique()
```

From the original Series `s`:

```
out = s.unique().drop_duplicates().str.extractall('([^:]+)')[0].unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['Stressful day', 'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Ate late',
       'Worked out'], dtype=object)
```

Other options (maybe less efficient):

```
out = set(x for s in a if isinstance(s, str) for x in s.split(':'))

out = pd.Series(a).str.split(':').explode().unique()
```

###### keeping NaNs:

```
s = pd.Series(a)
out = np.concatenate([s[s.isna()].unique(),
                      s.str.extractall('([^:]+)')[0].unique()])
```

Output:

```
array([nan, 'Stressful day', 'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Ate late',
       'Worked out'], dtype=object)
```

Or:

```
out = set(x for s in a for x in (s.split(':') if isinstance(s, str) else [s]))
```

Output:

```
{'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', nan, 'Stressful day', 'Worked out', 'Ate late'}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway I can get nan also?

Comment: as a NaN object or string? if you first convert to string this will easily keep it

Comment: Can you also add the expected output in your question for clarity?

Comment: as a NaN object @mozway

Answer (score 2):

Here's a python plus numpy solution.

Starting with a list rather than an object dtype array is simpler (the array layer doesn't add anything to this code)

```
In [2]: alist =[np.nan, 'Stressful day', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea', 'Drank tea',
   ...:        'Ate late:Drank coffee', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Worked out',
   ...:        'Drank tea:Worked out', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day',
   ...:        'Drank coffee', 'Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day:Worked out',
   ...:        'Drank coffee:Worked out', 'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea',
   ...:        'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea:Worked out',
   ...:        'Drank tea:Stressful day', 'Drank tea:Stressful day:Worked out',
   ...:        'Drank coffee:Stressful day:Worked out',
   ...:        'Drank coffee:Stressful day',
   ...:        'Ate late:Drank coffee:Drank tea:Stressful day', 'Worked out',
   ...:        'Ate late:Drank coffee:Worked out']
```

Handling the nan is problem, since it's a float, not a string:

```
In [3]: blist = [s.split(':') for s in alist if not np.isnan(s)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

In [4]: blist = [s.split(':') for s in alist]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

A float can't `split', and string can't be tested for a float value.  So let's make a utility function to catch the error.

```
In [10]: def foo(astr):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return astr.split(':')
    ...:     except AttributeError:
    ...:         return [astr]   # makes extend easier
    ...:         

In [11]: blist = [foo(s) for s in alist]

In [12]: blist
Out[12]: 
[[nan],
 ['Stressful day'],
 ['Drank coffee', 'Drank tea'],
 ['Drank tea'],
 ['Ate late', 'Drank coffee'],
 ['Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Worked out'],
 ['Drank tea', 'Worked out'],
 ['Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Stressful day'],
 ['Drank coffee'],
 ['Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Stressful day', 'Worked out'],
 ['Drank coffee', 'Worked out'],
 ...
 ['Worked out'],
 ['Ate late', 'Drank coffee', 'Worked out']]
```

And flatten the list with extend.  I might have included this in the blist creation:

```
In [13]: clist = []
    ...: for l in blist:
    ...:     clist.extend(l)
    ...:     

In [14]: clist
Out[14]: 
[nan,
 'Stressful day',
 'Drank coffee',
 'Drank tea',
 'Drank tea',
 ...
 'Worked out',
 'Ate late',
 'Drank coffee',
 'Worked out']
```

Then it's easy to apply the `np.unique`.

```
In [15]: u = np.unique(clist)

In [16]: u
Out[16]: 
array(['Ate late', 'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Stressful day',
       'Worked out', 'nan'], dtype='<U32')
```

Actually we don't numpy at all, Python set will do just as well

```
In [17]: S = set(clist)
In [18]: S
Out[18]: {'Ate late', 'Drank coffee', 'Drank tea', 'Stressful day', 'Worked out', nan}
```